# Magento 2.4 : How to save delivery comment in order and in database?

Tags: event-observer, magento2.4, onepage-checkout, plugin, extension-attributes

I'm using Magento 2.4.4 and PHP 8.1 . How can i use the order comment as show in screenshot but use it in shipping method as delivery comment and save comment in sales_order &quote table?

[image]

I have try observer but doesn't work. it not saving comment in the tables mention above, here is the snippet of the code:

```
<?php
namespace [vendor]\[module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SaveDeliveryCommentToOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $deliveryComment = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getDeliveryComment();
        $order->setData('delivery_comment', $deliveryComment);
        $order->save();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and javascript

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function (Component, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: '[vendor]_[module]/delivery-comment'
        },

        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe('deliveryComment');
            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Get value of delivery comment
         * @returns {String}
         */
        getValue: function() {
            return this.deliveryComment();
        },

        /**
         * Set value of delivery comment
         * @param {String} value
         */
        setValue: function(value) {
            this.deliveryComment(value);
        }
    });
});
```

template

```
<div class="field delivery-comment">
    <label class="label" for="delivery-comment"><span><!-- ko i18n: 'Delivery Comment' --><!-- /ko --></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <textarea class="input-text" rows="3" id="delivery-comment"
                  data-bind="value: deliveryComment, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"
                  name="deliveryComment"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you using 3party extension?

Comment: is there a way of using third party extensions for 2.4.4 version?